# Sync vs Immediate Async execution performance bench

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm interested in performance comparison of synchronous and asynchronous data conversion test in case if async function would return result immediately. Will this affect on execution time?

To check this, I wrote simple bench to check.

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const data = JSON.stringify((() => {
    const obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        obj[i] = i;
    }
    return obj;
})());

function convertSync (data) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
}

async function convertAsync (data) {
    return JSON.parse(data); 
}

const REPEAT_COUNT = 10000;

performance.mark("sync_start");
for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT; i++) {
    convertSync(data);
}
performance.mark("sync_end");

performance.mark("async_start");
Promise.resolve()
    .then(async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT; i++) {
            await convertAsync(data);
        }
        performance.mark("async_end");
    })
    .then(async () => {
        performance.measure("sync", "sync_start", "sync_end");
        performance.measure("async", "async_start", "async_end");

        console.log("REPEAT_COUNT", REPEAT_COUNT);
        console.log(performance.getEntries().filter(x => x.entryType === "measure"));
    })
```

I'm using Node v8.11.1 without any transpilers and getting following results.

```
PS D:\TestProjects\PerfTest\promisevssync> node .\index.js
REPEAT_COUNT 100000
[ PerformanceEntry {
    duration: 7825.5724,
    startTime: 383379071.208899,
    entryType: 'measure',
    name: 'sync' },
  PerformanceEntry {
    duration: 7836.966301,
    startTime: 383386896.834899,
    entryType: 'measure',
    name: 'async' } ]
PS D:\TestProjects\PerfTest\promisevssync> node .\index.js
REPEAT_COUNT 10000
[ PerformanceEntry {
    duration: 788.824201,
    startTime: 383405055.485299,
    entryType: 'measure',
    name: 'sync' },
  PerformanceEntry {
    duration: 798.591301,
    startTime: 383405844.370999,
    entryType: 'measure',
    name: 'async' } ]
```

As you can see execution time is the same. For higher repeat count numbers are still not differs much, so I believe that this is just a nose. Such results raises two questions:

1. Is this test correct?
2. Why?

I understand that I missing something, but it seems that I forgot to take some fundamental thing in to account.

Comment: "*In case if async function would return result immediately…*" it makes no sense that the function is asynchronous at all.

Comment: Let's start with, why do you assume that the "async" code should be slower than the sync version?

Comment: Notice that you're using deprecated perf_hooks API that won't work in Node 10. @Thomas You could expect a considerable lag from asynchronous loop itself with less efficient promise implementation. However, this is not an issue in Node.

Comment: @Bergi, it required by interface. I'm making some common interface and it is required to be async, so I had concern regarding performance calls as designing interface might work with few thousand calls per loop call.

Comment: @estus, Can you please describe why it is not an issue in Node? What the difference?

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer Because of efficient native promise implementation and high-resolution timer, as it was said. They are fast in Node and can be considerably slower in other engines (browsers). What is the deal with the interface? You could do `await convertSync()` with same result, this would result in async loop too but would be a tiny bit more efficient.

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer Doesn't sound like code with a loop over a few thousand asynchronous calls is performance-critical anyway

Answer (score 2):

For async-await to work your function should return  a promise which is not the case. So you are getting similar results since convertAsync is not truly async function. Internally what javascript does is wrap your function in resolved promise and since your promise is almost immediately resolved you see minimal diff in your results.

Take a look at https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 2):

> I'm interested in performance comparison of synchronous and asynchronous data conversion test in case if async function would return result immediately. Will this affect on execution time?

The measurements are correct but notice that what's measured is the performance of synchronous and asynchronous iteration, while data conversion stays synchronous.

Node.js has high-resolution timer, so promises themselves introduce only a slight lag 
that is negligible in comparison with time spent on `convertAsync` call.

This test with 10000 iterations confirms this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT; i++) {}
```

vs

```
for (let i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT; i++) {
  await null;
}
```

The measurements are 0.5ms for synchronous loop vs 9ms for asynchronous.

In contrast with a dry run, most of the time will be spent on `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but yes, I'm looking exactly on delta time between sync and async approaches and not on absolute one. It's small, and wondering why, as I was sure, that Promise based version, even with immediate result would be noticeable slower, but not few milliseconds slower. Such low deviation might be even considered as noise.

Comment: The difference could be bigger in browsers. It's more efficient in Node due to how event loop works. Yes, it could be noise. For this reason one loop may be not enough for statistically correct benchmark. Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/benchmark